# How exactly the rstrip() function works in Python

Tags: python, string, strip

Python's `rstrip()` function not returned output as expected. I would like to know
the functionality behind this function.

```
my_str = 'cisco.com'
print(my_str.rstrip(".com")
```

Expecting this result should be `cisco` but it returning `cis`.

Comment: Please add a clear question that's not answered by the [`rstrip()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

Comment: It removes any trailing `.` `c` `o` and `m`.

Comment: `rstrip` strips **characters** (and not word) from the right of the string. If you want to strip the .com, use regex like `re.sub(r'\.com$', '', my_str)`

Answer (score 1):

> [`str.rstrip([chars])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)
>
> The chars argument is not a suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped:

So you're passing 4 chars: `.`, `c`, `o`, `m`.

Since there's a `o` before the `.`, that's also removed as you provided the `o` as a remove char.